# Invert position of sublists

Tags: python, list, numpy, position

I have a list composed of several sublists:

```
list_1 = [[x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], [x3,y3,z3], [x4,y4,z4]]
```

How can I invert the position of the sublists so that it will look like:

```
list_2 = [[x4,y4,z4], [x3,y3,z3], [x2,y2,z2], [x1,y1,z1]]
```

without having to use a `for` loop.

I've tried `sorted(list_1, reverse=True)` but that apparently positions the sublists according to how big the values inside of them are.

Comment: Just for fun, you _could_ use `sorted` to sort by indices. You just need to use `enumerate` to decorate the list with its indices, sort, then undecorating by stripping the indices: `[item[1] for item in sorted(enumerate(list_1), reverse=True)]`. But this would be very silly…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
>>> list_1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [0,1,2], [6,5,3]]
>>> list(reversed(list_1))
[[6, 5, 3], [0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

or `[::-1]`:

```
>>> list_1[::-1]
[[6, 5, 3], [0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

or copy `list_1`, then [`reverse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#mutable-sequence-types) it:

```
>>> list_2 = list(list_1) # copy
>>> list_2.reverse()
>>> list_2
[[6, 5, 3], [0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

**NOTE**: `reversed`, `[::-1]` return reverse iterator / reversed copy of the list, while `list.reverse` modify the list in-place and does not return the list.

Comment: I knew there was an easier way to do that... or three :) Thank you @falsetru!